# Unable to Inject angular services in to dynamically loaded component

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

I have successfully loaded a component dynamically using **ComponentFactoryResolver** and everything is working as I expected. But my problem is , I have one service named **ComponentStoreFactory** which I have already injected in other components in my application and it's working fine but when I inject this service in to Dynamically Loaded Component I am getting the below error.

Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for the MyDynamicComponent

**Service(it's available in an independent module which already imported in app module)**

```
 @Injectable()
    export class ComponentStoreFactory {
      getComponent(componentName: string): any {
        if (componentName === (RegisteredComponents.SomeComponent as string)) {
          return SomeComponent;
        }

      }
    }
```

**Dynamic Component (When I add the second parameter in the constructor to inject service I am getting the error)**

```
export class MyDynamicComponent implements AfterViewInit {


  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,private componentStoreFactory : ComponentStoreFactory ) {
  }
```

**Module where the Dynamic Component used**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyDynamicComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [MyDynamicComponent],
    providers:[
        ComponentStoreFactory 
    ]
})
export class TestModule {

}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide plunker?

Comment: `MyDynamicComponent` has the respective `@Component({})`, right?

Comment: @yurzui I have to create it from scratch. The code snippets I have added is just renamed and posted from main application. I thought it's real scenario and I am getting the error only for dynamic component. Let me see I can create a plunker

Comment: @camaron Yes..Component is working fine and loading. The pblm is when I  inject the service (second parameter)

Comment: I think if i create plunker it will work

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/0nevC7jyjW39XqI8Je5I?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui I can able to inject the service in to same module where dynamic component resides. But the service I am trying to inject is available in another module

Comment: You didn't provide information about your architecture. Please reproduce it in my plunker

Comment: @yurzui Ok..I will try to reproduce it in plunker. But the plunker itself showing loading..

Comment: Try to reload plunker. It should work

Comment: @yurzui I tried the same in a POC and I couldn't reproduce it. So I resolved the dependency manually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441764/difference-between-reflective-injector-and-injector-in-angular

Comment: @JEMI I know. I am watching you:)

Comment: @yurzui It's a big application . So I tried all possible scenario from my app to reproduce it but unfortunately I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @yurzui Hopefully I will come up with a reproducing scenario