# Difference between Reflective Injector and Injector in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I tried to create dependency explictly using two ways. Both are almost same but I am little bit confusing what's the advantage of using Reflective Injector over the normal Injector and which one is recommended way?

**Using Injector**

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
constructor( private injector: Injector) {
    this.myService = this.injector.get(MyService);
  }
```

**Using Reflective Injector**

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
 constructor() {

       var injector= ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([MyService]);
       let myservice=injector.get(MyService);
     }
```

Comment: `Injector` is a container and can not create new providers. `ReflectiveInjector` has factory methods that allow you to define new providers at run-time (i.e. create new child injectors).

Comment: @ThinkingMedia child injectors means child dependencies?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I have a service which have no child dependencies . I want to explicitly create an instance of it. Which one is recommended approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An injector is a container with providers/services. It implements one method `get` and returns an instance of the service. Let's implement the most basic version of the injector in JS pseudocode:

```
class ReflectiveInjector {
   providers = [];

   static resolveAndCreate(providers) {
     providers.forEach((provider)=>{
         providers.push({token: provider.provide, instance: new provider.useClass})
     });  
  )}

  get(dep) {
     return providers.find((provider)=>{ return provider.token === token });
  }
}
```

Now, we need to create the instance of the injector before we can use it. And when we create it we define providers:

```
const existingInjector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([{provide: A, useClass: A }]);
const AInstance = existingInjector.get(A);
```

So you see in order to use an injector it has to be created first. It doesn't have any specific methods that allow adding providers so after it's created we can't add any new providers to it.

The injector you inject into the component constructor **is already created** by Angular. You can't add anything to it and can query only the providers already defined on it. If you need to provide `B` class, you can't do that with existing injector. You need a new one. And this is where `ReflectiveInjector` class comes in. It allows you to add new providers by creating a new instance of the injector and registering new providers. And the good part is that it can also setup an injector chain.

Let's a bit modify `resolveAndCreate` and `get` methods to allow chaining injectors:

```
class ReflectiveInjector {
   providers = [];
   parent;

   static resolveAndCreate(providers, parent) {
       this.parent = parent;
   ...
   }

   get(dep) {
       let found = providers.find((provider)=>{ return provider.token === token });
       if (!found && parent) {
            found = parent.get(dep);
       }

       return found;
   }
```

So now the only that left is to use it:

```
// passing existingInjector as a parent
const childInjector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([{provide: B, useClass: B }], i);
const AInstance = childInjector.get(A);
const BInstance = childInjector.get(B);
```

Now, suppose someone might want to get access to our `existingInjector`. We need a token to use to get this existing injector. Let's define this token like this:

```
abstract class Injector {}
```

and let's write a function that will get the existing injector:

```
function resolveDependency(token) {
   if (token === Injector) {
       return existingInjector;
   }
}
```

And now suppose that Angular when executes the constructor of the component, uses the tokens you specified to get dependencies and passes them to the `resolveDependency` function. So you write like this:

```
// the Injector here is a reference to our abstract Injector class and simply used as a token
MyComp {
   constructor(private injector: Injector) { ...  }
}
```

And the token here is `Injector` which as I said is passed into the `resolveDependency` function and the existing injector is returned.

Comment: I think the first class name is  Injector not  ReflectiveInjector. Can u pls confirm?

Comment: no, it's ReflectiveInjector, let me add some clarification

Comment: Ok..the last couple of lines clear the confusion for me. Thanks. One more doubt I have . When I use reflective Injector do I need to register the service  in my modules?

Comment: the question is what are you going to do with the reflective injector instance that you create?

Comment: @JEMI If you're able to register them in modules, you shouldn't use ReflectiveInjector at all. It is for rare cases when it should be done dynamically. It is a direct counterpart of `angular.inject` in AngularJS, and `angular.inject` was misused 99% of the time.

Comment: Yes. I have a service which I already registered in my module. I don't know when I inject the service in a dynamic component I am getting some error(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424018/unable-to-inject-angular-services-in-to-dynamically-loaded-component). I think it's a circular dependency issue. I couldn't find a resolution for it. That's why I tried this way and it's working

Comment: @estus Yes got it..Thanks for the clarification

Comment: if you already have a service defined in the module providers, you don't need to add it to the reflect injector instance you create. and if you don't need new providers, you don't usually need to create reflective injector instance. can you setup a plunker with your problem?

Comment: @Maximus my application is little bit big and I have created a POC locally with all possible scenarios and unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the same. But In my actual application the issue is still there. I know it's a circular dependency issue but I import the service in app module only. I don't know why angular still restrict to pass the dependency in constrcutor

Comment: @JEMI, sorry, can't help without the seeing the app

Comment: @Maximus Yes.I know. Hopefully I will come up with a reproducing scenario. Thanks a lot for your awesome explanation

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi I am not sure but are you sure that the following is not a typo?

  get(dep) {
     return providers.find((provider)=>{ return provider.token === token });
  }

On the return statement, the comparison of  "provider.token === token" instead of "provider.token === dep".
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: is it good to use injector class instead of doing a facade pattern where all services is placed in it?

Answer (score 1):

Angular will only create an instance once for each provider. Therefore, if you want to use the `Injector` as a factory you can't. You have to create a new injector for each new instance of an object you need.

So let's say we have a service class called `ReportsService` and it needs to create `Record` objects at run-time, but you want `Record` to be injectable.

Here's a class that we need to create multiple instances of.

```
@Injectable() // does not have to be defined in ngModule
export class Record {
      // just an example dependency that ReportsService doesn't know about
      public constructor(http: Http) {
      }
}
```

Here's the service that will create the above class.

```
@Injectable() // exported via ngModule
export class RecordsService {
      // we need injector as parent otherwise Record class will not find Http
      public constructor(private parent: Injector) {
      }

      // factory method
      public createRecord(): Record {
          // creates a new injector that knows about Record but extends existing injector
          let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
             {provide: Record, useClass: Record}
          ], this.parent);

          // first call, object is created
          let record = injector.get(Record);
          // just an example
          let example = injector.get(Record);
          // will output true
          console.log(record === example ? 'true' : 'false');

          return record;
     }
}
```

Now a new instance of Record is great, but what's the point if each object is exactly the same. So we need to inject parameters for `Record`. We'll create a token for a string value.

```
export const RECORD_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('record-url');

@Injectable()
export class Record {
      public constructor(http: Http, @Inject(RECORD_URL) url: string) {
      }
}
```

Now update the create function

```
 public createRecord(url: string): Record {
     let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        {provide: Record, useClass: Record},
        {provide: RECORD_URL, useValue: url
     ], this.parent);
     return injector.get(Record);
 }
```